# How to set image upload root for django application

Tags: python, django

I have trouble of setting up the root folder for uploaded images. The upload image is inside django application named api.

The view returns this link on image:
http://www.example.com/media/4a273bdf-564d-4dec-b657-43db27f04042.jpeg

However when I go on that link I get error because image is not on there.

I set in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ],
    'PAGE_SIZE': 1
}

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,STATIC_ROOT,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and I write this in api/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

def scramble_uploaded_filename(instance, filename):
    extension = filename.split(".")[-1]
    return "{}.{}".format(uuid.uuid4(), extension)

def filename(instance, filename):
    return filename

# Create your models here.
class UploadImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField("Uploaded image",upload_to=scramble_uploaded_filename)
    captcha_type = models.IntegerField("Image type")
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from api.models import UploadImage
from api.serializers import UploadedImageSerializer
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser,FormParser
import MySQLdb

class FileUploadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    #create queryset view
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = UploadImage.objects.filter(id=1,user='auth.User')
    serializer_class = UploadedImageSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import UploadImage # Import our UploadedImage model

class UploadedImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # current_user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = UploadImage
        fields = ('id', 'image','captcha_type','created','user','result') #
```

any ideas?

Comment: post the views how are you rendering the image and also the html

Comment: there is no html I'm using rest_framework.. I added models,views and serializers

Comment: so the link that you posted what would it show??

Comment: It would show image that was uploaded.. url is where it says that image is uploaded but it isnt

Comment: So what do you have that serves images at that URL?

Comment: Well when it was on local host i would click on the link and the browser would show image i didnt have any other html written. It was just click on image and it shows the image...

Comment: Click on url and it shows url all that I had to do before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi m8 all you have to do is edit urls.py add this lines and it should work.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (based on your comments below the OP) that you are trying to deploy this to a remote server:

The first thing to check would be that your image that you uploaded in fact exists at the path `[project root]/media/4a273bdf-564d-4dec-b657-43db27f04042.jpeg`.

The second thing to check would be that either Nginx or Apache or [insert web server] is properly routing requests to your `media` directory to the right location on your server.

**EDIT #1**

This is an example location block for your Nginx configuration file that routes requests from the url `www.example.com/media/filename_of_image.jpeg` to `/absolute/path/to/media/`:

```
location /media/  {
       alias /absolute/path/to/media/;
}
```

This should be placed within a `server` block, before your `location` block that defines the path `/`.

Comment: I'm using Nginx. Let me check I will get back to you.

Comment: Ok so path is in project root... folder media is in same place where manage.py is placed. The jpeg is there. so only thing to do is set properly routing requests to my media directory. Do you know how to do that?